# How to bind to list and sublist at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have data on the form that I want bound to combo boxes. Combo boxes need to display the same object at all times, and are bound to different properties of an object, but one of them displays only a subset of all possible objects.

My objects can be described as:

```
{"q",#1,1},{"w",#1,2},{"e",#1,3},{"r",#2,6},{"t",#3,2},{"y",#3,6} etc
```

first combo box displays the first field and full list, to be exact:

```
"q","w","e","r","t","y" etc
```

Second combo box displays the third field, but only for objects that have similar second field with currently selected object.

If {"q",#1,1} is selected, it displays:

```
1,2,3
```

and if {"r",#2,6} is selected, it displays:

```
6
```

Selecting another item in any of combo boxes changes currently selected item and (which updates other combobox accordingly).

What is the most elegant or 'right' way to do this using winforms data binding? (to me, elegat would be not resorting to handling changes of currently selected item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may helps:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int>> values = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();
```

Then:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item1";
comboBox1.DataSource = values;

comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Item3";

var filter = ((Tuple<string, string, int>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Item2;

comboBox2.DataSource = values.Where(input => input.Item2 == filter);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means comboBox2 data source must be changed any time comboBox1 selection changes, that is to say, in the handler of `SelectedItemChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property for each of your ComboBoxes to bind to. Now, the properties actually can be a LINQ expression, filtering the correct Data for you.

An example for such properties:

```
private final List<MyObj> _allObjects = new List<MyObj>();
... // fill the _allObjects somewhere


public IEnumerable<MyObj> AllGoodObjects 
{
    get { return from o in _allObjects 
                 where o.IsGood
                 select o; }
}

public IEnumerable<MyObj> AllBadObjects 
{
    get { return from o in _allObjects 
                 where !o.IsGood
                 select o; }
}
```

You can create complex query, and virtually select anything you want.

Comment: Not really seeing how bound controls will be set on the same object.